# I have access to 1000 cores across 10 nodes, what would be the best way to prallelize an MP2, GW, or RPA calculation for a periodic system in VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, computational-chemistry, high-performance-computing

What's the best way for parallelization in VASP for periodic systems? In the documentation, it mostly explains it for the local computer and molecule calculation. Apparently, these explanations don't help for periodic system calculations using supercomputer systems.

Let's say I want to do an MP2/GW/RPA calculation and I have access to 1000 cores (10 nodes each 100 cores). What would be the best way for me to make a good parallelization and have a fast result?

Comment: when it comes to parallelisation, the interconnection between the nodes/cores could be critical, can you please specify whether your 10 nodes are connected by specialised connection (e.g. Infiniband) or just LANs?

Comment: Must be just LANs but not 100% sure.

Comment: @bzbzbz it is very unlikely that the nodes are connected by ethernet. Most likely they are connected by Infiniband or Omnipath, and I think it's perfectly find to write your answer based on that assumption.

Comment: @NikeDattani You would hope that is true, but at my current university I have discovered that there are only 10 GBps links over standard ethernet between nodes.  As you can imagine, I tend to only run 1 node jobs but in massive parallel.
You may also want to see this question, it may be a duplicate. If it is not, then you may want to clarify why it isn't. https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2039/697

Comment: @TristanMaxson can you edit your previous comment to contain the next one? The two together fit in one comment and I'd like to reduce the # of comments so as to avoid making unnecessary chat rooms (I think we both agree we don't need a chat room just for this!). Ok I see you're trying to address the first one to me and the second one to Alfred. I'd still combine the comments and just start the 2nd one with something like "Alfred:"

Comment: I hit the 5 minute window, I also strongly suspect trying to avoid unneeded chat rooms is a task which cannot be accomplished in reality.  Eventually at least, they will come.  The real solution is getting the ability to someday delete them.

Comment: @TristanMaxson No worries about the 5-minute window, you combined the two comments into one, which is the more important part than address the user in the modified comment. I agree that we won't be able to ***entirely*** avoid the creation of new chat rooms, but we can try our best. As for being able to delete them in the future, it's very unlikely, since this would mean getting the SE company to allow it, and they don't usually respond positively to any feature requests.

Comment: You have 100 cores/node? That seems unusual. Perhaps you were just giving an arbitrary (and not necessarily realistic) example, but perhaps you can tell us what you *actually* have.

Comment: 100 cores / node is rather unlikely as there are no 50 or 100 cores CPUs on the market. Also, as far as I can recall there is a extensive discussion about paralelization in VASP talks of Martijn Marsman uploaded to Youtube by NERSC.